# Qt, Designer creates scrollAreaWidgetContents in scrollArea, and i cant resize my imagelabel

Tags: c++, qt

I have dragged a scroll area into the designer, then i dragged a label (imageLabel, for setPixmap). Then i have right clicked and set the layout to be grid.

```
scrollArea = new QS.....
scrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget();
gridlayout = new QGri..(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
imageLabel = new QLabel(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
gridLayout->addWidget(imageLabel,.....);

scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
```

So the designer have created above code, few parts left out, and i have now in my code set ui->imageLabel->setPixmap and trying to do ui->imageLabel->resize(200,200). But the image are always at full size 1600x1400 pixels).

The code examples around the net, it seems that they set the imageLabel directly into scrollArea and omits the scrollAreaWidgetContents? But i dont seem to achieve this from the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resize` is ignored most of the time when the widget is inside a layout.

You can use `setFixedSize` or `setMinimumSize` instead to force the size or a size smaller than the image.

You also need to set the `QLabel` `scaledContents` property to `True` (in the designer or with `QLabel::setScaledContents`) to scale the image to the label size.

Comment: Yes, i found out that it was some setScaledContent and also a property on the scrollwidget had some impact. Found out from the Image Viewer Example on Qt Docs.

Comment: setScaledContents(true) will zoom image to fit QLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout in designer. Change layout margins to zero. This should produce the same result as removing scrollAreaWidgetContents from the chain, and yet doable thru the designer.